# Determinant of the inverse of a Lorentz transformation

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

In many text book (Ashok Das Quantum Field Theory) $$(\Lambda^T)_\nu{}^\mu=\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$$ that gives $\Lambda^T$ = $\Lambda^{-1}$, where $\Lambda$ is Lorentz Transformation matrix. However, this is not general definition of transpose where rows and columns are exchanged. ie $\Lambda^i_j = \Lambda^j_i$.  Hence element of transpose is not obtained by exchanging the rows and column. It is also given that $det(\Lambda^T) =  det(\Lambda)$. However generally this is true when we take transpose (i.e rows and columns atre exchanged which not the case here). Is this just accidental that $det(\Lambda^{-1}) = det(\Lambda)$? or tru for any mixed rank tensor.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/158309/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169762/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237270/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144371/2451 and links therein.

Comment: $\Lambda^T \ne \Lambda^{-1}$

Comment: I think it is best to not mix matrix notation and Einstein notation. The matrix notation is unnecessary and less expressive in general

Answer (score 2):

The correct index structure of the matrices are $\Lambda^\mu{}_\nu$, $(\Lambda^{-1})^\mu{}_\nu$ and $(\Lambda^T)_\mu{}^\nu$ and the correct formulas are
$$
\Lambda^\nu{}_\mu = (\Lambda^T)_\mu{}^\nu = (\Lambda^{-1})_\mu{}^\nu.
$$
The last equality does NOT imply that in matrix notation $\Lambda^T = \Lambda^{-1}$ because their index structures are different. Instead, we should write
$$
(\Lambda^T)_\mu{}^\nu = (\Lambda^{-1})_\mu{}^\nu = \eta_{\mu\rho} \eta^{\nu\sigma}(\Lambda^{-1})^\rho{}_\sigma .
$$
We can now employ matrix notation and write
$$
\Lambda^T = \eta \Lambda^{-1} \eta^{-1} = \eta \Lambda^{-1} \eta .
$$
We can now take the determinant on both sides and we find
$$
\det ( \Lambda^T ) = \det(\eta) \det(\Lambda^{-1}) \det(\eta^{-1}) \quad \implies \quad \det \Lambda = \det ( \Lambda^{-1}) . 
$$

Comment: Doesn't$$\forall\mu:\forall\nu:(\Lambda^T)_\mu{}^\nu = (\Lambda^{-1})_\mu{}^\nu$$mean that $\Lambda^T = \Lambda^{-1}$?

Comment: No, because $\Lambda^{-1}$ and$\Lambda^T$ have different intrinsic index structures.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by different index structures?

Comment: I mentioned it in the first line but let me elaborate. The matrices $\Lambda$ and $\Lambda^{-1}$ naturally have its first index up and second index down whereas $\Lambda^T$ has its first index down and second one up. So when I write $\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu$ that does NOT represent a Lorentz matrix because its first index is NOT up and second one is NOT down. We must instead use the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ to raise/lower indices to bring it into proper form (1/2)

Comment: so we can write $\Lambda_\mu{}^\nu = \eta_{\mu\rho} \eta^{\nu\sigma} \Lambda^\rho{}_\sigma$ and now the indices on $\Lambda$ has the right form. The same thing applies to $\Lambda^{-1}$ as I've done in the answer (2/2).

Comment: I think I get the point now, thank you. So for example, $$\begin{pmatrix}\Lambda_0{}^0&\cdots&\Lambda_3{}^0\\\vdots&&\vdots\\\Lambda_3{}^0&\cdots&\Lambda_3{}^3\end{pmatrix}$$ is not the matrix associated to $\Lambda$, but the matrix associated to $\eta\circ\Lambda\circ\eta ^{-1}$, right?

Comment: That’s correct.

Answer (score 1):

If $\Lambda$ is a Lorentz matrix, then its inverse is $$\Lambda^{-1}= 
\eta \Lambda^t \eta$$ where the transposed matrix  has here the standard meaning and $\eta= diag(-1,1,1,1)$. Taking the determinant on both sides,  it holds,
$\det \Lambda^{-1} = \det\Lambda^{t} (= \det \Lambda)$ because $\det\eta=-1$. This fact is false in general but it is true for the elements of some matrix group like $O(n)$ and $Sp(n,R)$ in addition to the Lorentz group.

I finally stress that some groups of physical interest are such that the determinant of their matrices is $1$ by definition (think of the group of proper rotation or the special Lorentz group). In that case, the identity we are discussing is obvious since $\det A = \det A^{t}$.